# manage events in Haskell

Tags: haskell, jsdom, ghcjs, ghcjs-dom

I'm currently working with GHCJS.DOM/JSDOM in Haskell with the aim of create a small web application.
In order to capture the event "click on a button" I write the following code:

```
releaseAction <- on element click $ do
    w <- currentWindowUnchecked
    alert w "I was clicked!"
releaseAction
```

(this is an example taken from the page https://hackage.haskell.org/package/jsaddle-dom-0.9.4.1/docs/JSDOM-EventM.html);
the problem is the following:
if I remove the last line ( so I delete releaseAction), then I can click the "element" as many times I want and consequently firing the events as many times I want.
On the other hand if I don't delete the last line, this cancels the event, preventing me of firing even a single event.
My goal is to let the user to click only one time the "element" and then this event must be
forbidden.
How I can do the job?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`mfix`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Monad-Fix.html#t:MonadFix):

```
mfix $ \releaseAction -> on element click $ do
    w <- currentWindowUnchecked
    alert w "I was clicked!"
    releaseAction
```